# Intrinsic Matrix varies based on Chessboard size

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I tried calibrating the camera using Chessboard image. However, intrinsic matrix changes based on Chessboard size.

For instance, when chessboard size is 9 X 6, following is my intrinsic matrix:

```
array([[724.4304263406323, 0.0, 138.76084817643044], 
[0.0, 696.9800307076623, 160.38774335553987], 
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

However, when chessboard size is 8 X 6, following is the matrix:

```
array([[560.26828227,   0.        , 651.26205953],
       [  0.        , 561.31867764, 499.0549782 ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

would like to know why there is a difference in the matrices?

Comment: are the squares of equal size between the different boards? If not: Are you adjusting the size in your code? All in all, calibration isn't always stable and results can cary, even if you feed the same chessboard multiple times.

Comment: @Micka Size of squares are equal. (25 MM). Yes, you are right, when try the same chessboard multiple times, results are varying. I need this camera matrix to convert 2D screen coordinates to 3D coordinates. Not sure how to proceed when the matrix is varying significantly, could you help me?

Comment: if you are computing the distortion parameters too, you should have a look at the undistorted images, whether they make sense. You could try to verify a computed calibration with new chessboard images.